# Keycloak: How to import my users database?

Tags: keycloak, laravel-9

I have this app, PHP, working good, bunch of users. Now there will be a new app and I want to use keycloak to be the mais login portal for this new laravel 9 app. How can I import the users database to keycloak?

Want to login currently and register new users using keycloak and then redirect to the propper app. Hope can import users database to keycloak

Comment: Do you know @sventorben?